# htaccess redirect only if it has value after forward slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to apply the following htaccess rule only if there is a value after the forward slash of `/events/`

If I visit `/events/` (Don't do anything. DO NOT apply the htaccess rule)

But if I visit `/events/this-can be-anything/` (Apply the htaccess rule below)

```
RewriteRule ^events/(.*) /lp/events/index.php [L]
```

This is obviously not working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your regex pattern (.*) to (.+) to match at least one character after the uri.

```
RewriteRule ^events/(.+)$ /lp/events/index.php [L]
```