# Rewrite URL to specifi query parts Nginx

Tags: php, apache, nginx, url, url-rewriting

I have got a situation where I want to rewrite the following URLs and send my first URL parameter as `data` parameter and rest as `query` parameter

```
www.example.com/anything.jpg      //Skip - Do Nothing because its a file from root
www.example.com/anything          //anything == ?data=$1
www.example.com/something/b       //something == ?data=$1    b == &query=$2
www.example.com/certainly/b/c     //certainly == ?data=$1    b/c == &query=$2
www.example.com/anything/b/c.jpg  //anything ==  ?data=$1    b/c.jpg == &query=$2
www.example.com/but/b/c/d         //but ==       ?data=$1    b/c/d == &query=$2
```

so my first URL parameter will always be `data` and rest as `query` no matter what it has. I found this question here [htaccess redirect only if it has value after forward slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44171636/htaccess-redirect-only-if-it-has-value-after-forward-slash) and got it to some extent like

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/(.+)$ /handle.php?data=$1&query=$2 last;
```

It has some problems as this rewrites into following

```
www.example.com/anything.jpg      //Results in 404 Not Found
www.example.com/anything          //Results in 404 Not Found
www.example.com/something/b       //Working good
www.example.com/certainly/b/c     //data=certainly/b    query=c
www.example.com/anything/b/c.jpg  //data=certainly/b    query=c.jpg
www.example.com/but/b/c/d         //data=but/b/c        query=d
```

I tried playing around with different variations in `rewrite ^/(.*)/(.+)$ /handle.php?data=$1&query=$2 last;` but nothing worked

Comment: @mickmackusa Oh Sorry, I just forgot. I surely accepts it as the best answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that I can prove the regex matching outcomes, I'll demonstrate with `preg_replace()`, but the pattern should seamlessly translate to your script.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pNs6O))

```
$urls = [
    'www.example.com/anything.jpg',      //Skip - Do Nothing because its a file from root
    'www.example.com/anything',          //anything == ?data=$1
    'www.example.com/something/b',       //something == ?data=$1    b == &query=$2
    'www.example.com/certainly/b/c',     //certainly == ?data=$1    b/c == &query=$2
    'www.example.com/anything/b/c.jpg',  //anything ==  ?data=$1    b/c.jpg == &query=$2
    'www.example.com/but/b/c/d',         //but ==       ?data=$1    b/c/d == &query=$2
];

var_export(
    preg_replace('~www\.example\.com/(?![^/]+\.jpg)([^/]+)(?:/(.+))?~', 'www.example.com?data=$1&query=$2', $urls)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'www.example.com/anything.jpg',
  1 => 'www.example.com?data=anything&query=',  // note the empty query value
  2 => 'www.example.com?data=something&query=b',
  3 => 'www.example.com?data=certainly&query=b/c',
  4 => 'www.example.com?data=anything&query=b/c.jpg',
  5 => 'www.example.com?data=but&query=b/c/d',
)
```

Using a negated character class containing the slash for the first capture group will permit greedy (speedy) matching without matching too much.

The negative lookahead prevents matching a jpg file.

The second capture group is optional, so unless you want to write a separate pattern to match `data`-only urls, you'll need to tolerate the empty assignment.

For your purposes, my untested suggestion is:

One declaration:

```
rewrite ^/(?![^/]+\.jpg)([^/]+)(?:/(.+))?$ /handle.php?data=$1&query=$2 last;
```

Or as two declarations:

```
rewrite ^/(?![^/]+\.jpg)([^/]+)$ /handle.php?data=$1 last;
rewrite ^/(?![^/]+\.jpg)([^/]+)/(.+)$ /handle.php?data=$1&query=$2 last;
```

Comment: Hi Mickmackusa! Thanks for kind answer but I think there is some problem. You can test it https://www.regextester.com

Comment: If that had a demo on it, I cannot view it on mobile.  Do you want to describe the problem to me?  Or use regex101.com?  Going to bed now, I'll check in the morning.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mickmackusa! That was just super answer. Actually it was my mistake in understanding the regex. It's working great. And I went through your SE Profile. You are pretty straight forward and really your answer is just as you said in your profile. Love You

Comment: And to support all extensions instead of just `.jpg`, I replaced it with `.` is that ok? So, my final regex is ^/(?![^/]+\.`.`)([^/]+)(?:/(.+))?$

Comment: Actually, if you want to make sure that there are no extensions (dots) in the negative lookahead, you can more simply remove the `.` after `\.`.  Your requirement does not demand the matching of the alphanumeric substring (with a variable length after the dot.

Comment: Actually I want to skip if it is a request for a file like icon, png or xml or even index.html from the Root directory. So, I think I will have to keep the dot there in first query part. Because if I completely remove the Dot from first part, then it will also rewrite any file request from root.

Comment: Maybe I am unclear in my advice. Use `^/(?![^/]+\.)` to match the literal dot (start of an extension) in the negative lookahead. The extra (unescaped) dot that you wrote will match any character -- iow, it will match the first character of the extension and I don't think that there is any value in matching this character.

Comment: Oh I got it. Yes you are fabulous. You just pointed the right thing. You are regex Hero. Thanks once again for saving it.